# Basic functional programming understanding in GO

Tags: go

I'm new GO coder (stared this Sunday) coming from different backgrounds, I wrote the below code based on my understanding of Go within these couple of days, and impacted of my experience in other languages, I like to share for Go experts review/comments and feedback.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "sort"
    "time"
)

const (
    layoutISO = "2006-01-02"
    layoutUS  = "January 2, 2006"
    custom    = "1/2/2006"
)

type Inventories []Inventory
type Inventory struct { //instead of: map[string]map[string]Pairs
    Warehouse string
    Item      string
    Batches   Lots
}
type Lots []Lot
type Lot struct {
    Date  time.Time
    Key   string
    Value float64
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, 世界")
    date := "12/31/19" // "1999-12-31"
    t, _ := time.Parse(custom, date)
    var inventories = new(Inventories)
    var inventory = new(Inventory) // Or = Inventory{} both are working //warehouse[item[batch, qty]]
    inventory.Warehouse = "DMM"
    inventory.Item = "Helmet"
    inventory.Batches = append(inventory.Batches, Lot{t, "Jan", 10})
    inventory.InsertBatch(Lot{time.Now(), "Jan", 30})
    inventory.Batches.Insert(Lot{time.Now(), "Feb", 30})
    fmt.Printf("\nBefore grouping: %v %T\n", inventory, inventory)

    x := Inventory{
        Warehouse: "DMM",
        Item:      "Gloves",
        Batches: Lots{
            Lot{mustTime(time.Parse(custom, "1/7/2020")), "Jan", 50},
            Lot{mustTime(time.Parse(custom, "2/1/2020")), "Feb", 20},
            Lot{mustTime(time.Parse(custom, "1/5/2020")), "Jan", 40},
            Lot{mustTime(time.Parse(custom, "2/9/2020")), "Feb", 60},
        },
    }
    fmt.Printf("\nBefore grouping: %v %T\n", x, x)

    // Below can be used for grouping batches in each warehouse seperatly, this can be combined in the lines under
    //  inventory.Batches.Group()
    //  x.GroupBatches()
    //  fmt.Printf("\nAfter grouping: %v %T\n", inventory, inventory)
    //  fmt.Printf("\nAfter grouping: %v %T\n", x, x)

    // Above can be replaced by below
    inventories.Insert(*inventory)
    inventories.Insert(x)
    inventories.GroupBatches()

    fmt.Printf("\nInventories after gouping batches: %v %T\n", inventories, inventories)

    inventories.SortBatches()

    fmt.Printf("\nInventories after sorting batches: %v %T\n", inventories, inventories)
}

func (i *Inventories) Insert(x Inventory) {
    *i = append(*i, x)
}
func (i *Inventories) GroupBatches() {
    inv := new(Inventories)
    for _, el := range *i {
        el.GroupBatches()
        inv.Insert(el)
    }
    (*i).ReplaceBy(inv)
}

func (i *Inventories) SortBatches() {
    inv := new(Inventories)
    for _, el := range *i {
        sort.Sort(Lots(el.Batches))
        inv.Insert(el)
    }
    (*i).ReplaceBy(inv)
}

func (i *Inventories) ReplaceBy(x *Inventories) {
    *i = *x
}

func (i *Inventory) InsertBatch(x Lot) {
    (*i).Batches = append((*i).Batches, x)
}

func (i *Inventory) GroupBatches() {
    (*i).Batches.Group()
}

func (p *Lots) Group() {
    lots := new(Lots)
    lots.FromMap(p.Map())
    p.ReplaceBy(lots)
}

func (p *Lots) FromMap(m map[string]float64) {
    for k, v := range m {
        (*p).Insert(Lot{time.Now(), k, v})
    }
}

// Below to enable sorting: sort.Sort(Lots(lots))
func (l Lots) Len() int           { return len(l) }
func (l Lots) Less(i, j int) bool { return (l[i].Date).Before(l[j].Date) } // { return l[i].Key < l[j].Key }
func (l Lots) Swap(i, j int)      { l[i], l[j] = l[j], l[i] }

func (p *Lots) Insert(x Lot) {
    *p = append(*p, x)
}

func (p *Lots) ReplaceBy(x *Lots) {
    *p = *x
}

func (p *Lots) Map() map[string]float64 {
    sum := make(map[string]float64)
    for _, el := range *p {
        sum[el.Key] = sum[el.Key] + el.Value
    }
    return sum
}

type Interface interface {
    // Len is the number of elements in the collection.
    Len() int
    // Less reports whether the element with
    // index i should sort before the element with index j.
    Less(i, j int) bool
    // Swap swaps the elements with indexes i and j.
    Swap(i, j int)
}

func mustTime(t time.Time, err error) time.Time {
    failOnError(err)
    return t
}

func failOnError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error:", err)
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

The above code is fully functioning, and give the results as below:

````bsh
[Running] go run "d:\goplay\grouping.go"
Hello, 世界

Before grouping: &{DMM Helmet [{0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC Jan 10} {2020-06-05 00:26:16.9165066 +0300 +03 m=+0.006981101 Jan 30} {2020-06-05 00:26:16.9165066 +0300 +03 m=+0.006981101 Feb 30}]} *main.Inventory

Before grouping: {DMM Gloves [{2020-01-07 00:00:00 +0000 UTC Jan 50} {2020-02-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC Feb 20} {2020-01-05 00:00:00 +0000 UTC Jan 40} {2020-02-09 00:00:00 +0000 UTC Feb 60}]} main.Inventory

Inventories after gouping batches: &[{DMM Helmet [{2020-06-05 00:26:16.9175045 +0300 +03 m=+0.007979001 Jan 40} {2020-06-05 00:26:16.9175045 +0300 +03 m=+0.007979001 Feb 30}]} {DMM Gloves [{2020-06-05 00:26:16.9175045 +0300 +03 m=+0.007979001 Jan 90} {2020-06-05 00:26:16.9175045 +0300 +03 m=+0.007979001 Feb 80}]}] *main.Inventories

Inventories after sorting batches: &[{DMM Helmet [{2020-06-05 00:26:16.9175045 +0300 +03 m=+0.007979001 Jan 40} {2020-06-05 00:26:16.9175045 +0300 +03 m=+0.007979001 Feb 30}]} {DMM Gloves [{2020-06-05 00:26:16.9175045 +0300 +03 m=+0.007979001 Jan 90} {2020-06-05 00:26:16.9175045 +0300 +03 m=+0.007979001 Feb 80}]}] *main.Inventories

[Done] exited with code=0 in 3.624 seconds
```
````

Comment: Your title should state what your code does. Please read the relevant pages in the help center.